# Is trace( inv(A) B ) a distance?

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, trace, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

Given two symmetric p.d. matrices of dimension $(p \times p)$, $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$, can we interpret
$$
d = \operatorname{trace}(\mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{B})
$$
as a distance between the two?

For this it would obviously have to be the case that $d$ is minimized if $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{B} \Rightarrow d = p$. Is this the case?

Comment: @NinadMunshi $B$ is not positive definite.

Comment: Oh that's what the p.d. is. Nevermind on my obejction

Comment: While thinking of it as a "distance" is too much to hope for, it is at least invariant under similarity, i.e. $A \mapsto PAP^{-1}$ and $B \mapsto PBP^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. Consider the case $A,B$ are diagonal positive definite matrices. It is easy to make $d$ arbitrarily small/arbitrarily close/equal to $p$ without the matrices being close/equal.

To make this clear, let $x_1,..., x_p$ be arbitrary positive numbers with $x_1+...+x_p=p$. Set $A=I, B= \mbox{diag}(x_1,...,x_p)$.

Then $d(A,B)=p$.

Comment: Yes, obviously. Thank you. But would it make sense to say that if $d(A,B) > p$, then "$A < B$", as a size comparison so to say.

Comment: @stollenm With that definition you have $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0& 3 \end{bmatrix}< \begin{bmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}<\begin{bmatrix} 9 & 0 \\ 0& 1 \end{bmatrix}<\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0& 3\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you, got it.